# Scala covariance inferred type List[Any]?

Tags: scala, covariance

I came across the following Scala snippet that represents a `List` with a "cons" operator (similar to `::`):

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
    def ::[A](that: A) = Cons(that, this)
}

final case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
final case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

Why is `List[Any]` the inferred return type of `::`?

Comment: Because `def ::[A](that: A)` means that you introduced a new type parameter **A** _(different from the one of the trait)_ which doesn't relate with the existing type parameter **A** and since you didn't specify the return type of the method, the compiler tries to infer something that typechecks, so the **LUB** of `trait.A` _&_ `method.A` is **Any**. This is the correct definition: `def ::[B >: A](elem: B): List[B] = Cons(elem, this)` - As a rule of thumb, always use epxlicit return types.

Comment: Oh, so basically the method's `A` type shadows the trait's `A`. Hence by using `B` in the method we can then impose a relation between `B` and `A` (from the trait). Is that correct?

Comment: Mostly, while the traits `A` was shadowed for us to refer to it, it still exists for the compiler and for it the name doesn't matter it just know that is a different type than the one of `that`, so if the return value is `Cons(that, this)` it knows that the return type will be something like `Cons[A]` _(another different A)_ now let's do the **LUB** ourselves `Cons[A1](that: A2, this: A3)` so **A1 == LUB(A2, A3)** and since they do not have any relationship then the only valid type is **Any** thus the return type is `Cons[Any]`.

Comment: With `[B >: A]` we are introducing a new type parameter **B* that has to be either **A** or a supertype of **A**, so the **LUB(B, A) === B**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the clear explanation!